# What is the best option for long regular expressions in mapping task?

Tags: java, python, regex, pypi

I have a long dictionary of terminology about biomedical entities. Each term (key) has a list of identifiers (value).

I have to find this terminology in free text. I have several dictionaries around 300,000 terms, and for this task I am using Python and Java to evaluate speed.

The algorithm is like to (in Python):

```
for sentence in text_list:
    terms = dictionary.keys()
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(terms))
    matches = pattern.finditer(sentence)
    for m in matches:
        ini = m.start()
        end = m.end()
        match = m.group(1)
        save_result(ini, end, match)
```

I am using [pypi.python.org/pypi/regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package because the standard re package can not compile my long regular expression. Also, I have done the same algorithm in Java.

I am using around 650,000 sentences and in Python, the compilation takes 3-4minuts, and the algorithm can finish in 3-4 hours.

Java compile the regex in seconds but the algorithm takes 16-18hours...O_o

I have been reading different websites and http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html has an interesting information, but I do not know how to handle.

My question is... I have achieved to do all sentences in ~3 hours, do you know another way to achieve the same in less time? Maybe in other language, or using other library or package? (in Java, I am using the standard library `java.util.regex.*`). The above website talks about Thonpson NFA algorithm, there are libraries or packages of this algorithm for Java, Python or whatever? `grep` (Linux) is a powerful tool, do you think that I can use it?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are a wrong tool for this job. Create a dictionary (Python's name for a hash table) with your terms, split your text into words (using string.split and string.rstrip to remove punctuation), and check each word in the text against this dictionary.

Comment: One term can have several words. I have several rules to trasform each term and sentence (lowercase, delete puntmarks...). I would like to do soft-matching too. Do you think that a hash table (in python or Java) would be better?

Comment: @nathan: a `dict` *is* a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You're rebuilding and recompiling the RE for every sentence of your text. Compile it once outside the loop:

```
terms = dictionary.keys()              # why are you using a dict?
pattern = re.compile("|".join(terms))

for sentence in text_list:
    matches = pattern.finditer(sentence)
    # etc.
```

That should save you some time.

If you want an RE library with the algorithms described by Cox, look around for Python or Java bindings to his [RE2](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html) library. Alternatively, use `egrep` or Awk.

Comment: Yeeees!!! I am sorry, it was a typographical error, my compilations is outside the loop!!! Can I use egrep in JAVA or Python?

Comment: @nathan: For Python, see the `subprocess` module, for Java, you're on your own. Be careful with escaping, and be aware that you will encounter extra overhead due to interprocess communication.

Comment: Thanks!!! Should I be to use Lucene as an alternative? Could Lunece improve something? Or it is better, a first filter with egrep to get sentences with entities and after finditer to find offsets?

Comment: @nathan: this is getting a bit out of hand. Lucene is an indexing and FTS toolkit, not a `grep` replacement.

Comment: But Lucene can search words in full text (with sotf-matching I think...), no?